# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, environment-variables

I installed java jdk hotspot 1.7. When I type `java -version` I am getting:

```
java version "1.7.0" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
```

This is correct.

And I tried to install maven, and added to `/etc/environment` file:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4
M2=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin
```

Now When I type mvn I am getting:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.   We cannot execute
”/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0”/bin/java
```

However I am not putting " mark for JAV_HOME var in environment file.

It is trying to run from

```
”/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0”/bin/java
```

path, Actually it should be

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java
```

When I command

```
$JAVA_HOME
```

I am getting:

```
bash: ”/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0”: No such file or directory
```

I am sure the path(`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0`) is correct.

Comment: Can you do an `ls -al /usr/lib/jvm` and confirm that 'jdk1.7.0' is the format for the directory name?  When using Oracle, they tend to use weird folder names

Comment: `ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-7` and `ls "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7"/bin` yield, and should yield the same result for me (which is not empty). The last part, java-7, is the result of a manual modification - it can and will be a bit different for you. Verify, that such a folder exists (jdk1.7.0).

Comment: I got `total 44
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jun 28 01:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 184 root root 36864 Jun 28 01:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x  10 root root  4096 Jun 27 23:30 jdk1.7.0
` after running this `ls -al /usr/lib/jvm ` command

Comment: Note that to see a variable in your console, you are expected to type: `echo $VARNAME`. If you just do `$VARNAME` then it will execute what's in that variable.

Answer (score 16):

`JAVA_HOME` should be set to the name of the directory that [*contains* the `bin` directory](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-set-javahome-environment-in.html) that *contains* the Java executables (in particular, `java` itself).

Assuming you do have a `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0` directory, it probably contains a `jre` subdirectory that contains the `bin` directory that contains `java` and related executables.

So you should probably be setting `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre` rather than `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0`.

Comment: Installing a JDK, not just the JRE usually lead to a JDK-directory containing a bin dir, as well as a JRE-dir, which itself contained a bin dir. But `JAVA_HOME` was always set to the parent dir, not to the `jre` dir.

Comment: Interesting, I need to set it to jdk no? I am going to write code in java, compile, deploy, etc..

Comment: @Kamoliddin If Maven is using `$JAVA_HOME` to know where `javac` and other development binaries are, then yes, you'll need to set it to the `jdk` dir containing the `bin` dir that contains those binaries.

Comment: Thanks, I do not know, it worked after restart, I think i do not need to restart for changes to be applied. I did not change anything. It worked.

Comment: Not sure why he using jdk1.7.0 at all.. `/usr/lib/jvm/java` should suffice for both `java` and `javac`. Alternatives takes care of this